# Не записывается в сессию

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, сессия

В общем такие дела я через ajax на php страничку гоню данные и там их записываю в сессию после перезагружаю страницу и в массиве вывода сессии нечего не появляется сайт на битриксе. Вот код отправки данных:

```
$('.btn-price').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addtobasket.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                'id': <?=$arResult["ID"]?>,
                'name': '<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>',
                'img': '<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>',
                'qty': $('input[name="qty"]').val(),
                'price': $('input[name="price"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status == "OK") {
                    alert("Товар добавлен.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Вот код работы в файле:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]])){
    //если в массиве уже есть добавляемый товар
    $_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]]['qty'] += $_REQUEST["qty"];
    //total_quantity();
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'OK']);
} else {
    //если в корзине нет такого товара
    $_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]]['name'] = $_REQUEST["name"];
    if ($_REQUEST["img"] != "") {
        $_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]]['img'] = $_REQUEST["img"];
    }
    $_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]]['qty'] = $_REQUEST["qty"];
    $_SESSION['card'][$_REQUEST["id"]]['price'] = $_REQUEST["price"];
    //total_quantity();
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'OK']);
}
```

Я уже голову сломал в чем проблема подскажите может дело вовсе и не в коде.

Comment: где начало сессии то ваше?

Comment: @teran это же битрикс начало сессии где-то у него в прологах

Comment: главное эти прологи заинклудить. в логе ошибок то есть чего? request id присутствует?

Comment: @teran как раз таки инклудов то и нету, как только подключил все заработало

Comment: 99% процентов вопросов с _"в сессию ничего не пишется"_ связаны с тем что старт сессии не вызван (явно или не явно). оставшийся один процент будет связан с тем что сервер не может файлы сессии на диск записать по причинам отсутствия прав или места.